# Variable updating wrong in loop - Python (Q-learning)

Tags: python, q-learning

Why does the position and newposition give the same output and update together in the next loop?

```py
for game in range(nr_of_games):
    # Initialize the player at the start position and store the current position in position
    position=np.array([0,19])

    status = -1
    # loop over steps taken by the player
    while status == -1: #the status of the game is -1, terminate if 1 (see status_list above)

        # Find out what move to make using  
        q_in=Q[position[0],position[1]]

        
        move, action = action_fcn(q_in,epsilon,wind)
        
        # update location, check grid,reward_list, and status_list 
        
        newposition[0] = position[0] + move[0]
        newposition[1] = position[1] + move[1]
        
        print('new loop')
        print(newposition)
        print(position)
        
        
        grid_state = grid[newposition[0]][newposition[1]]
        reward = reward_list[grid_state]
        
        status = status_list[grid_state]
        status = int(status)
        
        if status == 1:
            Q[position[0],position[1],action]= reward
            break #Game over 
            
        else: Q[position[0],position[1],action]= (1-alpha)*Q[position[0],position[1],action]+alpha*(reward+gamma*Q[newposition[0],newposition[1],action])
           
        position = newposition
```

print out:

```
new loop
[16 26]
[16 26]
new loop
[17 26]
[17 26]
new loop
[18 26]
[18 26]
new loop
[19 26]
[19 26]
new loop
[19 25]
[19 25]
new loop
[20 25]
[20 25]
```

Comment: Where is `newposition`  defined ?

Comment: If you actually have `newposition = position` in there, then I would expect this.  In that case, both names are bound to the SAME array object.  Changing one changes the other.  I'm not sure why you're using `numpy` here, but seeing as you are, you can just write `newposition = position + move` and avoid this.

Comment: `newposition[0] = position[0] + move[0]` would fail unless `newposition` already exists.  That's what we were asking.

Comment: You can only subscript pre-existing objects.

Comment: Please do not deface your question, especially after someone has put in the effort to answer it. This is not a polite or proper thing to do.

Comment: Even if you delete things your instructors can still see it in cached pages. Best to avoid posting "sensitive" information in the first place. Lesson learned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because you trying to copy one list to another list with `=` operator; used with lists it assigns the pointer stored in right variable to the left variable, so physically the point to the same memory cells.

To copy a list truly, use the `list.copy()` method.

Comment: The same happens with all mutable containers (not just lists), sets, dicts, and any other container can trip you up. 
Actually the behaviour of `=` is exactly the same on all objects, but when the object is immutable the fact you don't get a copy isn't a problem. Beginners expect `=` to give them a copy and it doesn't.

Also note that if the list is a list of lists then list.copy() wont solve the problem - for nested containers you might want the deepcopy() of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, somewhere you do not show us, you do

```
>>> newposition = position
```

So actually, when you increment `newposition`, you actually are doing it over `position` as well.

So just make `newposition` be something different than `position`. I mean, make them have `id(newposition) != id(position)` and you will be good. Because currently, I guess that these two [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)s are the same, aren't they ?

> Why does the position and newposition give the same output and update together in the next loop?

Because they are the same object. I am not (only) saying that they are equal, I am saying that `newposition` is `position`, i.e. you currently have `(newposition is position) is True`.

Just define `newposition` independently from `position`. For example:

```
# [...]
for game in range(nr_of_games):
    # Initialize the player at the start position and store the current position in position
    position    = np.array([0,19])
    newposition = np.empty((2,))
    # [...]
```

---

Also, you may have good reasons to do so, but keep in mind that if `move` and `position` have the same shape and convey the "same information", you could also just do

```
# [...]
    # [...]
        # [...]
        # newposition[0] = position[0] + move[0]
        # newposition[1] = position[1] + move[1]
        newposition = position + move
        # [...]
```

and remove `newposition = np.empty((2,))`.